# Prove that if $x$ is rational then $y$ is rational as well.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be two real numbers in $(0,1)$ such that the $n$th decimal digit of $y$ (after the decimal) is the $2^n$th decimal digit of $x$. Prove that if $x$ is rational then so is $y$.

Here is an example, if $x=0.12345678$ then $y=0.248$.

Clearly if the decimal digits of $x$ terminate then $y$ is rational. So we only have to consider the case where $x$ is nonterminating.

Let $$x=0.a_1a_2...a_na_1a_2...a_na_1...$$

Then $$y=0.a_{2\pmod n}a_{4\pmod n}a_{8\pmod n}...$$
$$\quad \text{ if $2^k\equiv 0\pmod n$ then we let $n=2^k\pmod n$}$$

So we need to show $2^k\pmod n$ is eventualy periodic. Here is my attempt,

Let $S=\{2^k\pmod n\mid k\in \mathbb Z^+\}$. Obviously $S\subseteq\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ which means $\exists i>j$ such that $$2^i\equiv 2^j\pmod n\implies 2^{i+s}\equiv 2^i\pmod n$$
Where $s=i-j$. Is my proof correct?

Comment: You need to add something to prove periodicity. You have just shown, that for every $j$ exists such $s$ that for every integer non-negative $m$: $2^{j+ms}\equiv 2^{j} \pmod n$. You need to show that exists $s$ such that for every $j$ (maybe starting from $j_0$) $2^{j+s}\equiv 2^{j} \pmod n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that for $a, n$ coprime we have $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1$ (mod $n$), where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. Here we have $a = 2$ so there are three cases to consider (all formulas are mod $n$):

(1) When $n$ is odd, then $2$ and $n$ are coprime and we have $2^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1$. Therefore:

$$\forall i \ge 1, \; 2^{i + \varphi(n)} \equiv 2^i$$

(2) When $n$ is a power of 2, and $n = 2^{\nu}$, we obtain:

$$\forall i \ge \nu, \; 2^i \equiv 0$$

(3) Finally, when $n$ is even but not a power of $2$, we write $n = 2^{\nu} n'$, with $n'$ odd, in which case we find that:

$$2^{\nu} ( 2^{\varphi(n')} - 1) \equiv 0$$

This implies:

$$\forall i \ge 1, \; 2^{i + \nu + \varphi(n')} \equiv 2^{i+\nu}$$

and is equivalent to:

$$\forall j > \nu, \; 2^{j + \varphi(n')} \equiv 2^{j}$$

This proves that $2^k$ (mod $n$) is indeed eventually periodic for any n.